# function with variable returns for routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have multiple routes which need the same userdata from the database. I have a function to check if the user is loggend in but that function dont return the user variables.

route:

```
app.get('/template', isAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
  MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, client) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    const db = client.db(dbname);
    let collection = db.collection('users');
  // find data in db
  collection.findOne({ _id: userid }).then(user => {
    if (user != null) {
      res.render('template', { layout: 'temaplte', csrfToken: req.csrfToken(), username: user.username, avatar: user.picture });
    } else {
      console.log("No user with this id!")
    }
  }).catch((err) => { console.log(err);
  }).finally(() => { client.close(); });
});
});
```

Is there a way to get the variables `users` from the db from a function like `isAuthenticated`? Do I need to write the `findOne-function` on every route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to reuse logic in routes is to refactor that functionality into its own middleware.

```js
function loadUserData(req, res, next) {

  MongoClient.connect(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  }, (err, client) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err)
    };
    const db = client.db(dbname);
    let collection = db.collection('users');
    // find data in db
    collection.findOne({
        _id: userid
      }).then(user => {
        if (user != null) {
          req.user = user; // augment the request object with user data (check res.locals docs too)
          return next(); // pass control to next middleware

        } else {
          res.end("No user with this id!");
        }
      }).catch((err) => {
        return next(err);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        client.close();
      });
  });

}

app.get('/template', isAuthenticated, loadUserData, function(req, res) {
  const user = req.user; // loadUserData populated req.user;
  res.render('template', {
    layout: 'temaplte',
    csrfToken: req.csrfToken(),
    username: user.username,
    avatar: user.picture
  });

});
```